# Ways to provide user files to an executable

Tags: python, file, executable

I made a Python script and now i would like to distribute it to others by converting it to a .exe using PyInstaller.

This script reads a users Excel sheet to grab information, so i would need the executable to be able to know which file to read.

Is there a simple way to make it so that anyone can have their file analysed? In this case, like dropping the .xlsx file with a specific filename into the executable directory so that the executable can read many different Excel sheets for many different people?

In other words, i was wondering if there's a way that i could just make it so that it would be as simple as a drag and drop of an Excelsheet into the executable file directory and then have others run the .exe

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: get the file path using `input` and the user should be able to drag and drop the file into the terminal and get the path: `filepath = input(File path: )`

Comment: You could use Tkinter or PyQT to open a regular OS file picker

Comment: @It_is_chris that's genius! Simple and effective. I think that's the easiest way so I'll try that. Thank you!

Comment: @MontX No problem and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering how are you specifying file name, by hard coded full name?
Dragdrop file is a good idea but may not be cross platform.
You can simply ask user to put excel file **besides** the exe(NOT desktop!), and double click exe.
The code will scan files in current directory:

```
import os

# help you know where user is running
print(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))
for f in os.listdir():
    # or any other criteria
    if f.endswith('.xlsx'):
        print(f)  # process the file here
        break # if you only want process one file
```

Comment: This sounds like it would work great! I may have to consider it. My only concern is that it may breakdown if there are multiple Excel files in the desktop. Would that be an issue?

Comment: i updated answer accoring to your comments.